# Sum over primitive Dirichlet characters

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-character

Take $q,n\in \mathbb N$.  I want to evaluate exactly
\[ S_q(n):=\sum _{\chi }\tau (\chi )\chi (n)\]
where the sum extends over *primitive* characters modulo $q$ and where $\tau (\chi )$ denotes the Gauss sum
\[ \tau (\chi ):=\sum _{a=1}^q\chi (a)e\left (a/q\right ).\]
I guess I would like the $n$ dependence "separated", whatever this might mean.

If I open up the Gauss sum then
\[ S_q(n)=\sum _{a=1\atop {(a,q)=1}}^qe\left (a/q\right )\sum _{\chi }\chi (an)\]
but I don't know if I can say anything sensible about the inner sum.  All I can think of is writing it down explicitly (in terms of indices and primitive roots), which I think means writing it as
\[ \sum _{h=1\atop {(h,q)=1}}^qe\left (hv(an)/q\right )=c_q\left (v(an)\right )\]
so that
\[ S_q(n)=\sum _{a=1\atop {(a,q)=1}}^qe\left (a/q\right )c_q\left (v(an)\right )\]
but I still don't see how I can write the $n$ dependence in any useful way.

Am I missing something or is it just not possible?

---

---

Small note: Ultimately I will be summing over
\[ \sum _{q|Q}f(q)\]
so perhaps it's only possible to get a sensible formula after summing over all $q$.  But $f$ doesn't have a factor $\chi _0(n)$ (mod $Q$) so I wouldn't know how to combine the primitive characters altogether.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. i've edited, let me know if it still doesn't make sense.

Comment: I made a stupid mistake let me write the correct answer

Comment: don't worry, no stress:)

Comment: There is $S_{p^k}(n) = \sum_{a=1}^{p^k} \exp(2i\pi a/p^k) (\varphi(p^k) 1_{an=1\bmod p^k}-\varphi(p^{k-1}) 1_{an=1\bmod p^{k-1}})$ and $S_{uv}(n)=S_u(vn)S_v(un)$ whenever $\gcd(u,v)=1$.